# Why Nancy is not automatically registering the DefaultFluentAdapter to IFluentAdapterFactory?

Tags: nancy, fluentvalidation

This is more a "Why should I?" than an actual issue.

I've decided to integrate FluentValidation as stated in NancyFX docs

[NancyFX FluentValidation Integration](https://github.com/NancyFx/Nancy/wiki/Nancy-and-Validation)

The docs state that nothing else needs to be done. So I installed the package from NuGet as this

```
Install-Package Nancy.Validation.FluentValidation -Version 1.4.1
```

And then updated the root validator that comes referenced with the Nancy.Validation.Fluentvalidation

```
https://www.nuget.org/packages/FluentValidation/
```

I created a simple validator pretty similar to docs just to test it out.

And when running this sentence in a NancyModule

```
this.Validate(user);
```

I get an error like this

```
An exception of type 'Nancy.Validation.ModelValidationException

No model validator factory could be located. Please ensure that you have an appropriate validation package installed
```

So... after digging up a little bit I just told myself, ok, if the factory is not found, maybe no one (TinyIoC) is resolving IFluentAdapterFactory dependency that I assumed that was missing. So I found that actually there is an implementation for the adapter factory that's built-in the package, and thats the DefaultFluentAdapterFactory

So wiring this in the bootstraper solves it.

```
container.Register(typeof (IFluentAdapterFactory), typeof (DefaultFluentAdapterFactory));
```

Is it supposed to be automatically discovered?
Or may I be doing something wrong to get it Not-Set by default?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I've the same issue, only manual registration solved it